# CRUD de muchos a muchos ASP.NET EF con checkbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

Tengo un base de datos con tres tablas: Programador, Lenguaje y ProgramadorLenguaje (esta se genera de un mucho a mucho) buscando aprender a usar los checkbox, donde busco registrar un programador y que indique que lenguajes de programación domina(estos los elegiría desde un listado de checkbox cargado desde la tabla Lenguaje "java","C#","PHP"),posteriormente editar esta información pero lo que he encontrado para ilustrarme solo me muestra una tabla, no tengo claro lo que hay que hacer(la que se usa para explicar es la tabla que se genera del M:M), así sería mi diagrama de base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ha costado entender lo que he visto y no doy con como implementar, agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas. Así como está, tu pregunta puede ser cerrada

Comment: como realizaste el mapping de estas entidades en EF ? como obtienes los datos de asp.net mvc en el action al marcar los check para convertir esto en esntidades que aplicas el dbcontext. Podrias mostrar algo del codigo que hs implementado